# Connecting to a sql server database using LocalDB with a renamed extension

Tags: visual-studio, localdb, mdf

I've created a database but I'm not using the standard mdf and ldf extensions.  I can attach and work with the database with no problems using SSMS: (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB

From Visual Studio when I try to add a connection to the same database (I'm selecting Microsoft SQL Server Database File), I get the following error:

*An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file "d:\test.md" failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.*

If I rename the extension back to mdf, the connection works. How can establish a localdb connection to this file?  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Why do you want a different file extension? (This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: The database will be deployed to end users and I don't want to make it obvious that this is a sql database. The fact that this works in SSMS, I would think it should also work from Visual Studio.

Comment: SSMS uses more of SQL Server than the minimal version that is SQL Express LocalDB. Behaviour being different is not a surprise. You might also be running into issues with the DB already being opened into one instance of LocalDB and creating a new one. (For these reasons I tend to just use full SQL Server and not need top worry). Probably useful to read up on the different kind of local DB instances ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15)) and also specify the connection string you are using.